# CakePHP 3: Preselect checkboxes when editing belongsToMany Model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a Workshop model which belongs to many Speakers through workshops_speakers:

```
class WorkshopsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config) 
    {
        $this->table('workshops');
        $this->displayField('title');
        $this->primaryKey(['id']);

        $this->belongsTo('Times', [
            'foreignKey' => 'time_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);

        $this->belongsToMany('Speakers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'workshop_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'speaker_id',
            'joinTable' => 'speakers_workshops'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Creating workshops and assigning speakers and a time to workshops works fine. However, if I want to edit a workshop, the possible speakers show up, but the assigned speakers are not preselected automatically (saving works, if I just select some speakers when editing - the assigned Time is also being preselected automatically). My input in edit.ctp looks like that:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($workshop); ?>
...
echo $this->Form->input('time_id', ['type' => 'select', 'multiple' => false, 'class' => 'form-control']);
echo $this->Form->input('speakers._ids', ['multiple' => 'checkbox']);
```

WorkshopsController::edit()

```
/**
 * Edit method
 *
 * @param string|null $id Workshop id.
 * @return void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
 * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
 */
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $workshop = $this->Workshops->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Speakers']
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $workshop = $this->Workshops->patchEntity($workshop, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Workshops->save($workshop)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The workshop has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The workshop could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }

    $times = $this->Workshops->Times->find('list');
    $speakers = $this->Workshops->Speakers->find('list');

    $this->set(compact('workshop', 'times', 'speakers'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['workshop']);
}
```

In my Workshop Entitiy I've also assigned "speakers" as accessible:

```
protected $_accessible = [
    'title' => true,
    'date' => true,
    'description' => true,
    'type' => true,
    'sort' => true,
    'meta' => true,
    'time_id' => true,
    'speakers' => true,
];
```

I am using a virtual field for Speaker to display the first and lastname beneath the Checkboxes. In SpeakersTable::initialize():

```
$this->displayField('full_name');
```

In the Speaker Entity:

```
protected function _getFullName() {
    return $this->_properties['first_name'].' '.$this->_properties['last_name'];
}
```

tl;dr: List of speakers available is being displayed, but associated Speakers to Workshop are not being preselected when editing a Workshop. Everything else works fine.

Comment: Please show your complete `edit()` action code, and your `Form::create()` call. On a side note, your first code example is broken, the method calls should be in the `intiialize()` method.

Comment: Added the edit() (which has been created by cake bake) and Form::create() call. The missing initialize method was just a copy&paste error.

Comment: Was the missing `contain` option value that you've added afterwards a copy & paste mistake too? Because apart from that I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: I've added the contain option a while ago, it does not change anything. When creating a new Workshop the data is saved correctly: I can get the associated Speakers when listing the Workshops.

Comment: My bad: It was indeed the contain option. After adding the option I also changed the Form input call to assign the associated speakers manually via 'val', which unfortunately resetted the selects, because the given array was empty. Removed the 'val' and now it works. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved, I forgot to add the contain option value in WorkshopsController::edit().

```
$workshop = $this->Workshops->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Speakers']
]);
```

I didn't see, that it was working after adding the option since I tried to select the checkboxes manually in edit.ctp at the same time, which resetted them.